# Keyboard overlapping textfields

Tags: flutter

I am creating a class to edit some user fields:

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: AppColors.rojoMovMap,
            title: Text("miperfil".tr()),
          ),
          body:  SingleChildScrollView(
            child:Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "tuemail".tr(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: AppColors.grisMovMap,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              widget.usuario.email,
                              style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.grisMovMap, fontSize: 16),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
    
                        SizedBox(height: 5,),
                        TextField(
                          controller: controladorUsername,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          maxLength: 18,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            icon: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                //verificar que no existe ya el username
                                //asignar nuevo username
                              },
                                child: new Icon(Icons.edit,color: AppColors.rojoMovMap,)),
                            labelText: "tuusername".tr(),
                            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
    
                        TextField(
                          controller: controladorUbicacion,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
    
                                  //asignar nueva ciudad,provincia
                                },
                                child: new Icon(Icons.edit,color: AppColors.rojoMovMap,)),
                            labelText: "tuubicacion".tr(),
                            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
    
                        TextField(
                          controller: controladorPais,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
    
                                  //asignar nuevo pais
                                },
                                child: new Icon(Icons.edit,color: AppColors.rojoMovMap,)),
                            labelText: "tupais".tr(),
                            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
    
                        TextField(
                          controller: controladorNombre,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
    
                                  //asignar nuevo nombre
                                },
                                child: new Icon(Icons.edit,color: AppColors.rojoMovMap,)),
                            labelText: "tunombre".tr(),
                            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
    
                        TextField(
                          controller: controladorApellidos,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
    
                                  //asignar nuevo apellidos
                                },
                                child: new Icon(Icons.edit,color: AppColors.rojoMovMap,)),
                            labelText: "tusapellidos".tr(),
                            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: controladorApellidos,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
    
                                  //asignar nuevo apellidos
                                },
                                child: new Icon(Icons.edit,color: AppColors.rojoMovMap,)),
                            labelText: "tusapellidos".tr(),
                            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: controladorApellidos,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          autocorrect: false,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            icon: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: (){
    
                                  //asignar nuevo apellidos
                                },
                                child: new Icon(Icons.edit,color: AppColors.rojoMovMap,)),
                            labelText: "tusapellidos".tr(),
                            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
        );

  }
```

The issue is that the keyboard is overlapping some textfields:

[image]

As you may see in the code,I have wrapped the column that contains the textfields with a `SingleChildScrollView` and I have included  `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,` inside the scaffold.

What am Im I missing?

Comment: just remove this line `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,` everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

test this example

```
return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        ),
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              //your code here
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```